# bike grease got on my wall. best way to get it off?

Tags: road-bike

white paint on drywall. 
black bike grease.

whoops.

what are you tips and tricks for getting it off the wall/paint

Comment: First, dab up any loose grease with an absorbant towel/rag.  (DO NOT rub it in!)  Then try dish detergent (diluted) on a rag.  Be careful to not soak the area.  Rinse well.  If that fails, try one or two of the "degreaser" cleaners -- 409, ZEP, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably best to start with something mild and work to more harsh until you find something that works. It's probably also best to test in a non-conspicuous area on the same wall just in case something unexpected happens. You can start with just soap and water, and see how that does.Then try dish soap. If that doesn't work, you could try the [magic eraser](http://www.mrclean.ca/en_CA/magic-eraser.do) things. They do sell [generic ones](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EZGIU0C) which people claim to work (never tried them) which could save money if you need to do this a lot. I think these actually remove a thin layer of paint, so you should probably be careful with these.

Comment: You are correct, Magic erasers are essentially very fine sandpaper. This is fine on most flat paints.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using window cleaner and a clean rag (old shirt) to clean anything from painted walls. Window cleaner works like a combo of mild soap and alcohol solution – very effective against grease. If used carefully, it doesn't leave any marks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd spray the area with a stain remover/detergent something like vanish maybe add a little bicarb of soda for an extra bit of abrasiveness.

Then use a sander with a medium/fine grit sandpaper. to get the grease off.
With a bit of luck you will not have to take it all the way down through the coats of paint.
Then once removed give it a good wipe down

If you do go too deep you can always do a little retouching (if you have matching paint)

I used this same technique on a painted/plastered internal wall during a house renovation that had some realllllly stubborn mould that even bleach wouldn't remove.

Answer (score 0):

Try GooGone (citrus based) or dish soap. In my experience one of those will get rid of the grease.

Answer (score -5):

I am using [Acetone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetone). It dissolves all kinds of paints, varnishes and stuff.
For rusty parts and oxidized terminals [WD-40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WD-40) is the answer.

Good luck !

Comment: The question is grease off a painted wall.  Why would you use a product that dissolves paint.  Nothing in the question about rusted parted and oxidized terminal.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer but I think the acetone would remove the paint.

Comment: Acetone will dissolve the paint.

Comment: And it's a carcinogen.

Comment: Why do you only see the paint in this picture ... Did you had hard time reading " WD-40 " It dissolves all kinds of rusty/grassy stuff ?

Comment: The OP desires to remove grease from a wall. I think it is safe to assume that he or she does not want to remove the paint. Hence, Acetone would be a problem. Using WD-40 for removal of rust and oxidized terminals is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I do not think that you understand the line above that I wrote. So please do not read only the first comment, because it is not only the acetone that is mentioned. WD-40 is also used for removing greasy stuff. I use it to remove the worn grease out of my bike, so just because it mainly used for that, I will refrain from quoting all the things that it is good for.